# How to simplify the time-ordered exponents?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

How to simplify time-ordered exponents $e^{iH_1t/\hbar}e^{-iH_2t/\hbar}$?

If $H_1$ and $H_2$ presumably don't commute, will $e^{iH_1t/\hbar}e^{-iH_2t/\hbar}$ be presented by a exponential integral？

Comment: You probably want [The Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula) for this...

Comment: I once considered Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula, but if they don't  commute, the expansion terms in the formula could reach infinite, which makes it even harder to solve.

Comment: If your matrices don't commute, then you're not going to get any formula more explicit than that except in some very special cases. When you say 'solve', what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I wonder if the two exponential parts can be combined into one. Correct, no explicit expression involved.